# Live Streaming Between Two Devices With 4G Network

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3

i want to cast live streaming video from Linux machine i.e Raspberry Pi to another Linux/Windows/Android Machine.

Both system have 4G Internet connection (No Public IP),
Is there a way that i can accomplish this thing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. One of the widely used framework is GStreamer. You can think of media framework tool like GStreamer.

You can used UDP for communicating the data from your Pi to host machine.

GStreamer allows you to stream video with very low latency.

[Reference of Gstreamer with Pi.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=112354)